# Should async lamda run in async function?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

So I have the following code with a few more methods other than Set or Delete but I'll keep it short for simplicity:

```
public byte[] Get(string key)
{
    byte[] Action() => this.Cache.Get(key);
    return this.Execute(Action);
} 

public void Delete(string key)
{
    void Action() => this.Cache.Delete(key);
    return this.Execute(Action);
}

private void Execute(Action action)
{
    this.Execute(() =>
    {
        action();
        return 0;
    });
}

private T Execute<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        try
        {
            return action();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Now I want to make this code async. I've tried doing:

```
 public async Task<byte[]> GetAsync(string key)
 {
     async Task<byte[]> Action() => await this.Cache.GetAsync(key);
     return await this.Execute(Action);
 }

public async Task DeleteAsync(string key)
{
    void Action() => this.Cache.DeleteAsync(key);
    await this.Execute(Action);
}


private void Execute(Action action)
{
    this.Execute(() =>
    {
        action();
        return 0;
    });
}

private T Execute<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        try
        {
            return action();
        }
        catch (RedisConnectionException)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

It compiles and seems to work, but I have no idea if it is actually async or not. It seems weird that the Execute method is not async and does not return a Task. I did not find a way to make the Execute method async without getting errors and warnings. 
So my question is: In the second version of the code, will the executtion of the action

```
return action();
```

be async or sync?

Bonus question: Is there a way to test if something runs async or not? A way I could manually verify the "asyncness" of the code

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "runs async".  Code is asynchronous when two things happen: (1) methods representing high-latency work return quickly to their callers, and (2) the continuation of the high-latency workflow is scheduled to execute after its completion.  Are those things happening in your program? What are you really asking here?

Comment: If the thread will be not blocked so that it can perform other operations while waiting for the cache to respond.

Comment: The question "what does this code do when I run it?" can be answered by *running it*.  Run it, and see if the thread blocks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the first thing to cover is that a method being asynchronous doesn't mean "it has the `async` keyword on it."  A method is asynchronous when it returns to the caller very quickly, and then finishes whatever operation was asked of it *after returning to the caller* and allowing the caller to go on to do whatever it wants.  Usually this also involves some way for the caller to know when the operation has finished, whether it was successful or not, and sometimes to include some result of the operation.

What the `async` keyword does is just allow that method to have the `await` keyword in it.  If you didn't mark the method a `async` it wouldn't know if any usages of `await` in there were actually just regular variable names rather than a special keyword.  What `await` does is say that you want the method to schedule whatever code follows the `await` to run after the task you are awaiting has finished.

With that in mind we can go through your methods and see what they're doing, and if they're asynchronous.

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetAsync(string key)
{
    async Task<byte[]> Action() => await this.Cache.GetAsync(key);
    return await this.Execute(Action);
}
```

So lets look at just the inner method first:

```
async Task<byte[]> Action() => await this.Cache.GetAsync(key);
```

This performs an asynchronous operation, `GetAsync`, schedules a continuation to run after it finishes that does...nothing...and then returns the exact result that `GetAsync` returned.  So other than some overhead involved in adding continuations, this method is identical to just writing out:

```
Task<byte[]> Action() => this.Cache.GetAsync(key);
```

Now when we look at the method it's in:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetAsync(string key)
{
    return await this.Execute(Action);
}
```

We can see that this method, too, calls an asynchronous method, adds a continuation to it that does...nothing...and then returns the result of executing that method exactly as is.

Now on to the next method, again, looking at the inner method first:

```
void Action() => this.Cache.DeleteAsync(key);
```

Here we're calling an asynchronous method, but we're not returning the `Task` that it gives us.  This means we have no way of knowing when the operation finishes, or if it was successful.  Since `DeleteAsync` is asynchronous (or so we can assume, given the name), we know this method will return as soon as it has *started* the asynchronous operation, rather than after the underlying operation is done.

```
public async Task DeleteAsync(string key)
{
    await this.Execute(Action);
}
```

This doesn't compile.  `Action` here is a method that returns `void`, so you're calling the overload of `Execute` that returns `void`, and you can't `await` a `void` expression.  If you changed the code to:

```
public async Task DeleteAsync(string key)
{
    Task Action() => this.Cache.DeleteAsync(key);
    await this.Execute(Action);
}
```

Then it would compile, because you'd be calling the version of `Execute` that accepts a `Func<T>` and returns the result, so you'd be able to await that task, but, as we've seen from the earlier methods, awaiting it doesn't do anything useful other than add some overhead, we could just return the task and be done with it.

```
private void Execute(Action action)
{
    this.Execute(() =>
    {
        action();
        return 0;
    });
}
```

If we make the change pointed out above this wouldn't ever be called, as we'd never be passing in a delegate that returns `void`.

```
private T Execute<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        try
        {
            return action();
        }
        catch (RedisConnectionException)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

This is where things get complicated.  In our above examples both methods return *something*, so this overload is called.  Both of those somethings are tasks of some sort.  So this code will check the condition just fine, and go on to "//do something else" if it's false just like with the synchronous version.  Unfortunately, it will then go on to return the default value, which for a `Task` is `null`.  That's probably bad.  When that task gets returned someone is likely to `await` it at some point, and then they'll just get null reference exceptions.  What the callers probably *want* to happen here is to get a `Task<T>` whose result is the default value.

If the condition is true though it will call the asynchronous method, compute the task representing the results of that operation, whenever it finishes, and return it.  Relevantly, if the operation ends up failing at some point and returns a faulted task *your catch block won't run*.  The `catch` block will only run if `action` throws an exception instead of returning a faulted task.  (Which most asynchronous methods don't do.  In particular, any `async` method will  *never* do this.)

Re-writing `Execute` to have an `ExecuteAsync` verion is fairly simple though.  Rather than accepting functions that return some result, or void, you need to accept functions
that return a `Task<T>`, or `Task`, and return a `Task<T>` or `Task` instead.  Other than that the only real thing to do is `await` any task any time you want the rest of the code to not run until that task has finished:

```
private Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> action)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        try
        {
            return await action();
        }
        catch (RedisConnectionException)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

And then the overload for method with no result in their task:

```
private Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action)
{
    return this.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        await action();
        return 0;
    });
}
```